# Wrong date formatter?

Tags: objective-c

I have:

```
//date
    Wed Sep 10 19:21:08 +0000 2014

NSString *date=[twt objectForKey:@"created_at"];
 NSDateFormatter *df = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init]  ;
 [df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
NSDate *newdate = [df dateFromString:date];


 NSLog(@"%@",date); //good Wed Sep 10 21:13:46 +0000 2014
  NSLog(@"%@",newdate);// NULL
```

The `NSDate` returns NULL , when the date string is as shown.

Comment: See:
[ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Comment: I have checked that, couldn't figure what is the problem here.

Comment: from twitter i get the date

Comment: Strip and leading/trailing whitespace/newlines from the string.

Comment: strange, this is the exact code i run , and i get NULL..

Comment: here is the date string , i have log it again and again :  Wed Sep 10 21:13:46 +0000 2014 , i even had few others..

Comment: check my edit to see how i log it

Comment: thanks, your log gives : 'Wed Sep 10 14:56:30 +0000 2014' so i guess the string is ok .

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

solved with :

```
         NSString *date= [twt objectForKey:@"created_at"] ;
        NSDateFormatter *frm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [frm setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]  ];
          [frm setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
          NSDate *newdate = [frm dateFromString:date ];
```

Comment: Paraphrasing Carly Simon: "You're so vain, you probably think I down voted this" - I didn't. Well, it is a bad downvote of an answer, there should be a reason provided so it can be corrected or at least warn potential users of the answer, as you always do, right? Only "bad people" would down vote a good answer.